# Cannot Boot Windows 10 x86 from bootable USB after installing Ubuntu 18.04 (Full Wipe)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bios, bootable-media

I recently wiped my `64GB SSD` completely & `installed`**`Ubuntu 18.04`** on my computer.

After some time, I decide to go back to Windows. So, I tried making a bootable `Windows 10 32-bit` by formatting USB to **`fat32`** & then using `woeusb` to flash image on that USB.

I was able to reach the boot menu in BIOS, where on I chose USB option, pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I was staying in the boot menu all the time.

I've tried multiple potential fixes, using rufus, changing usb, trying usb on another computer (which worked just fine), changing boot options in BIOS. See the image below for current Boot configurations.

[image: Boot Configurations]

Comment: Is your boot USB created for UEFI or legacy boot or both?

Comment: @harrymc ive tried the GPT and MBR options in Rufus with no success.

Comment: You might need a BIOS update. What are your motherboard model and current BIOS version?

Comment: It's actually a Chinese tablet I got as a gift long time ago. Runs windows by default. The bios manufacturer is Phoenix Technologies. Image below shows system info: http://imgur.com/7aC2fIn